# Ionic translate ngx-translate

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ngx-translate

When translating a string in ionic it works when calling for one key in `en.json`
like so: `{{ 'key' | translate }}` but does't work on nested keys like so: `{{ 'key1.key2' | translate }}`

What I did so far is create a `shared.module.ts` and imported it in various needed pages with this code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

// import ngx-translate and the http loader
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

// required for AOT compilation
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient): TranslateHttpLoader {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, '../../assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    // ngx-translate and the loader module
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  exports: [
    TranslateModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

And this in `app.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {

  public languages: string[] = ['en', 'ar'];
  public language: string = this.languages[0];

  public appPages = [];

  constructor(
    public platform: Platform,
    private translate: TranslateService
  ) {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.translate.addLangs(this.languages);
      this.translate.setDefaultLang(this.language);
      this.translate.use(this.language);
  });
  }
}
```

This is my `en.json` file:

```
{
    "app_title": "app title",
    "app_subtitle": "app subtitle",
    "login": {
        "title": "login",
        "subtitle": "login"
    }
}
```

So as said `{{ 'app_title' | translate }}` works perfect
but `{{ 'login.title' | translate }}` doen't where result would print the key 'login.title' and not the actual translation

PS versions are:

```
"@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix was move the code `in shared.module.ts` to `app.module.ts`.

Code to be moved is:

```
// import ngx-translate and the http loader
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

// required for AOT compilation
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient): TranslateHttpLoader {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, '../../assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    ...,
     // ngx-translate and the loader module
     HttpClientModule,
     TranslateModule.forRoot({
       loader: {
         provide: TranslateLoader,
         useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
         deps: [HttpClient]
       }
     }),
    SharedModule
  ],
```

We should add the TranslateModule to the imports of all pages like so:

```
imports: [
  ...,
  TranslateModule
]
```